# The algorithm compares two lists, synchronization tables

Tags: java, algorithm, list, synchronization, compare

The algorithm compares two lists list, synchronization tables

I need to do to synchronize the local table with the table loaded from the server. It was decided to compare the two stages a list (local list and the server). Initially, the list was sorted. It remains a landmark in the comparing of id.

If id is on the local list is, and a server is not present, then the removal of entries from the local database (delete). If id is equal to the local server and then update (update). If id is the server there, and there is no local, to add (select). The problem I have just in the phase comparison, somewhere wrong, something not foreseen.

I throw off the comparison algorithm, that I began to write, but could not finish the image and example. Please modify it. Image example: http://c2n.me/3mMgiZg

```
List<Integer> server = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> local = new ArrayList<>();
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);


Iterator<Integer> serIter = server.iterator();
Iterator<Integer> locIter = local.iterator();

int item1 = serIter.next();
int item2 = locIter.next();
while(serIter.hasNext()) {
    if (item1 <item2) {
        db.addCourse(item1);
        item1 = serIter.next();
    } else {
        if (locIter.hasNext()) {
            while (item2 < item1) {
               db.deleteCourse(item2);
               item2 = locIter.next();
            }
            if (item1 == item2) {
                db.updateCourse(item1);
                item2 = locIter.next();
                item1 = serIter.next();
            }
        } else {
            while(item1<item2) {
                db.addCourse(item1);
                item1 = serIter.next();
            }
            if (item1 == item2) {
                db.updateCourse(item1);
                item1 = serIter.next();
            } else { 
                db.deleteCourse(item2 );
                continue other;
            }
       }
}
other:
    while(item1>item2) {
        db.addCourse(item1);
        item1 = serIter.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: You obviously have problems with your English. May be you should try [Stack Overflow на русском](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. If you simply want to make the local List = the server List, I would do something like as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < server.size(); i++)
{
    local.set(i, server.get(i));
}
```

This would iterate through all the items in the server ArrayList and change them to the value in the local ArrayList

Comment: no, server list may > local list, or server list may < local list, or server list may == local list

Answer (score 0):

- If the element occurs in both lists -> update item.
- If the element only occurs on the local list -> remove item.
- If the element only occurs on the server list -> add item.

Am I right? If so there are two ways to achieve your goal (only second solution asumes sorted lists).

The first attempt is slow but short:

```
List<Integer> remove = new ArrayList<>(local);
List<Integer> update = new ArrayList<>(server);
List<Integer> add = new ArrayList<>(server);
remove.removeAll(server);
add.removeAll(local);
update.retainAll(local);
```

The second solution performs better than the first one:

```
List<Integer> update = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> remove = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> add = new ArrayList<>();

int i, j;
for (i = 0, j = 0; i < local.size() && j < server.size();) {
    int l = local.get(i);
    int s = server.get(j);
    int cmp = Integer.compare(l, s);
    if (cmp == 0) {
        update.add(l);
        i++;
        j++;
    } else if (cmp < 0) {
        remove.add(l);
        i++;
    } else {
        add.add(s);
        j++;
    }
}
for (int k = i; k < local.size(); k++) {
    remove.add(local.get(k));
}
for (int k = j; k < server.size(); k++) {
    add.add(server.get(k));
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. First solution is not good idea, because if we need update 1 record or insert, and we have 2 000 local records, it's will be bad.
second solution, we need to check all of the options: when the number of elements of the server large number of items of local or vice versa and .... oh, I forgot to add a picture of my examples